# Context initialization issue for controller Unit testing with Spring 3.2 and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm trying to provide a clean Unit Test for a Controller of mine. This Controller has a Service as dependency and this Serviceh has a Datasource as dependency.

The test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class ContentActionWebServiceControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Test
  public void getRequestActionList() throws Exception {
    when(...)
    perform(...);
    verify(...);
  }

  @Configuration
  @ImportResource("...")
  static class MyTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
      return Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
    }
  }
}
```

And the MyService is something like

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  private MyDataSource myDatasource;

  ...
}
```

Because MyService as an Autowired property MyDataSource, the context isn't initialized because it doesn't find any MyDataSource type for satisfying the @Autowired annotation of MyService. But why does it ever try to resolve this annotation? Is this is a mock?

Comment: Could you add the stack-trace to your question please? It might help people answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito does use cglib to create a new child class of `MyService` (and override all methods with mock methods).

But still, the dependencies of the parent will be injected, because this is how Spring does it's job:

if you have a parent class with some `@Autowired` fields, and a child class that inherits from this parent class, then Spring will inject the `@Autowired` fields of the parent when instantiating the child. I guess it's the same behavior in your case.

If you use an interface for `MyService`, then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Indeed, that was my mistake. MyService is now an interface and that works. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: And as kryger says, I would suggest you annotate setters rather than the private members, so that you can unit test your classes with no dependency injection. Just create mock and inject them into the tested object using the setters. Unit tests should not use dependency injection at all.

Answer (score 1):

If it's supposed to be a unit test (and not an integration test) you don't even need to use Spring, you can do it all with JUnit+Mockito. Rather than `@Autowire`ing dependencies from Spring context, you can simply create mocks of the support objects (via `@Mock`) and inject them to the testee (via `@InjectMocks`). I believe your code could be simplified to something (conceptually) like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ContentActionWebServiceControllerTest {

  @Mock
  private Service mockServiceUsedByController;

  @InjectMocks
  private YourController testee;

  @Test
  public void getRequestActionList() throws Exception {
    assertFalse(testee.getRequestActionList().isEmpty());
    // etc.
  }
}
```